# Fulltext search with PHP and mySQL - altering table not an option

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a php/mysql query question regarding a half-finished project I took over recently.

The project is an online shop programmed in php using a mysql database which is also connected by an ERP (C++) software. 
The ERP and the half-finished online shop were done by the same programmer, but my customer is quite unsatisfied by the result of the shop.
Since the programmer refuses to work together with me, I'm stuck regarding an otherwise quite simple problem.

I need to do a fulltext search across two fields which both do have a fulltext index. It'd be a simple "SELECT ... MATCH ... AGAINST", but it does not work as expected. 
If I take e.g "tree" as a search item, the query finds everything with "tree" but not "Tree", or "TREE" and so on...
My first guess was to change the collations of the fields into something different than latin1_general_cs but unfortunately the ERP doesn't seem to like that very much.

I read somewhere that there's some possibility to convert the needed fields into something more useful on-the-fly within the query string, but I couldn't figure it out.

Maybe someone had a similar problem?

Comment: Changing the collation is going to be your best bet. What do you mean when you say "the ERP doesn't seem to like that very much"?

Comment: I agre with Ben D that changing the collation is your best bet. Running functions on columns in the WHERE part of your query will severely influcence the performance of your queries in MySQL.

Comment: @Ben D: I don't know how he did this, but as soon as I change the collation to latin1_general_ci all German Umlauts are displayed wrong within the ERP. The more I think about this, the more I come to the same conclusion.  
The guy is a jerk and he is offended by the fact that "his" customer has given the task to me. But I'll try again to talk to him on monday. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
Select * from myTable where LOWER(column) like '%tree%'
```

you will get all Tree, TREE, tree from the table if present

Comment: If the database is sizable this is going to be SLOW. The OP is using a fulltext index, which makes me think he might need to speed associated with such an index. Also, given that the OP is current using a fulltext index you're going to want it to be `like 'tree%'` or `like 'tree'` to match functionality (depending on what the original fulltext query looks like). You cannot do a fulltext search that leads with a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can stick the columns in your MATCH clause in a LOWER() function. If you make sure to only pass lower case strings into your AGAINST clause (or wrap them in their own LOWER()), you won't have this problem.

Comment: monitorjbl, you mean something like this?  
`SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE MATCH(LOWER(description)) AGAINST('tree')`  
Unfortunately that does produce an error...